# While loop and Cursor code in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: an input table and a calculated query which generates the result from the input table. I m trying to create a loop that updates the current base rate by 1 digit through loop and then the query calculates to update the current amount  based on the new incremental base rate until the current amount equal to or greater than the target amount. I have it working fine with one provider ID but if I have multiple IDs it doesn't work properly I am not sure what I am missing.

Input table

```
Provider ID   | Current Base Rate
---------------------------------
A             |      650
B             |     640
C             |     670
```

Calculated query: OpSummary

```
Provider ID | Current Amount    |     Target Amount
------------------------------------------------------
A           |        250        |           300
B           |        150        |          200
C           |        75         |         100
```

This is the code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPOPLoopTest] 
AS
     Declare @targetAmount money
     Declare @BASERATE Float
     Declare @CurrentAllowed money

 Set @targetAmount = cast((Select Max(t.TargetAmount)from[dbo].[opsummary]as money)
 Set @BASERATE = (Select Max(CurrentBaseRate)from[dbo].[InputTable] t)
 Set @CurrentAllowed = cast((Select Max(t.CurrentAllowed)from [dbo].[opsummary]t)as money)


Declare OPHosp Cursor For select t.Provider_ID from InputTable t 
Open OPHosp
Fetch Next from OPHosp
While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
Begin
   while (Select Max(t.CurrentAllowed)from [dbo].[opsummary]t)<=(Select Max(t.TargetAmount)from [dbo].[opsummary] t )
   begin

       if @CurrentAllowed>=(Select Max(t.TargetAmount)from [dbo].[opsummary] t) 
          break; 

       else

       begin

           Exec [dbo].[SPOpSummary]
           update [dbo].[InputTable] set CurrentBaseRate = @BASERATE

           set  @BASERATE = @BASERATE+1

           continue;
       end;

    end

end
```

Fetch Next from OPHosp

close OPHosp
Deallocate OPHosp

Comment: please fix formatting

Comment: can you show the sample data and expected output? It's currently unclear what the expected output SHOULD look like (versus what it currently looks like)

Comment: Thanks For replying.The output is the Op Summary Query....There is a detail query that generates this summary which is hard to share. But Basically the base rate in the input table determines the Current allowed. The simple version would be Base rate*Weight =Current allowed. in this case Base rate of 650*0.39 (Weight)=250 (Current Allowed).The Target allowed is already given and the only variable is the base rate so by incrementing the base rate by 1 it should eventually hit the target allowed. I hope this helps

Comment: Cn you show the desired output?

Comment: The desire outcome is to have the current amount equal target allowed by increment the base rate with  loop code in the input table. so basically  provider A would be 300 on the current amount which equal the target allowed and the B provider would be 200 as the target amount.. etc. The code as it stands right now works on the first line only but for some reason it is not doing the same for B and C

Comment: I failed to mention that OPsummary query that I m referring to above is a Stored procedure which create a table called OPSUMMARY... That is why in my code I m calling to execute the OPSUmmary to calculate each time when the base rate changes so it will check if the current amount are equal to the target allowed if not it will loop again and update the base rate by 1 digit till the current amount equal the target allowed.